# cmdkey delete credentials with dashes and spaces on the name " -"

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, credential-manager

cmdkey seems to be unable to delete credentials by target name when said name includes a space and a dash `-`

I have a credential `Test Credential - Iteration1` which I want to delete, but when I try

```
cmdkey /del:Test Credential - Iteration1
```

I get `The command line parameters are incorrect.` since I guess it's taking the dash as a new parameter.

So far I've tried quotes, double quotes, 2 double quotes, escaping the dash with ^, enclosing with {} and none of those work:

```
cmdkey /del:Test Credential - Iteration1
cmdkey "/del:Test Credential - Iteration1"
cmdkey /del:"Test Credential - Iteration1"
cmdkey /del:{Test Credential - Iteration1}
cmdkey {/del:"Test Credential - Iteration1}
cmdkey /del:{LegacyGeneric:target=Test Credential - Iteration1}
```

How can I delete with cmdkey the credential `Test Credential - Iteration1`

EDIT:
I validated that the command works for names without spaces. I created `TestCredential-Iteration1` and the following command deletes it successfuly

```
cmdkey /del:TestCredential-Iteration1
```

Comment: I thought it was `/delete` not `/del`, i.e `cmdkey /delete:FullyQualifiedDomainNameOfServer`.

Comment: They are equivalent. And I tried with both all the alternatives. The documentation only specifies /delete though, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: What displays when you use the `/LIST` option?

Comment: `Target: LegacyGeneric:target=Test Credential - Iteration1

    Type: Generic

    User: 9a004233-bf81-4741-b640-74ed99553b5f

    Local machine persistence`

Comment: You put double quotes around the parameter, which you have not done above. `cmdkey /del:"TestCredential-Iteration1"`

Comment: I did try it, I listed this as one of the examples of things I tried
`cmdkey /del:"Test Credential - Iteration1"`

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue. First I found this code:

```
cmdkey /list | ForEach-Object{if($_ -like "*Target:*"){cmdkey /del:($_ -replace " ","" -replace "Target:","")}}
```

https://gist.github.com/janikvonrotz/7819990, which allowed me to delete all credentials except the one with spaces. Then I ran this:

```
rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr
```

from here: https://forflukesake.co.za/wp/clear-credential-manager-fast/ and that opened up the gui and allowed me to remove it.

Comment: I followed the forflukessake url and finally found an easy way to edit my credentials. Thank you!